# using a locally stored version of an image

Tags: php, html, image-upload

I have a page that the user can upload an image to and then move around and resize using jquery draggable and jquery resizable.

To save on mutilple requests to the server, would it be posible to use the locally stored version of the image to speed things up and then have a save button which would only upload the image to the server when requested.

I have tried to do this unsuccessfully as I am only getting the temp location of the file

```
<?
$posted=$_REQUEST['posted'];
if($posted!='')
    {
     $image = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']."/".$_FILES['file']['name'];  
     ?><img src="<? echo $image ?>" width="480" height="360" /><?
     echo "posted=".$image;
    }
?>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="posted" value="1" />
 <input type="file" id="file" name="file" size="30" /> 
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the uploaded file using `move_uploaded_file()` to the destination you want.

Comment: Thats the whole point of the question, can I not use the local version using the file path of its current location and then move the file at a later date when I update the database

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "resize the image on the user's computer in their browser and then upload once the cropping is done" then no.

As far as I am aware that's not possible unless you use Flash or a Java plugin for example.

The `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` variable contains the temporary location of the uploaded file on the server. Temporary files are removed regularly, so to keep the uploaded file on the server you need to use `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: no the resizing parameters will be sent to an array and that array will be passed to the db on 'save', what I want is the image to be  shown on the page without it having to be uploaded to the server. I can then upload the image later on when the user clicks save. The reason for this is because there are many other things happening on the page and I want to save on server requests and also not interupt the page with the time it takes to upload the image.

Answer (score 0):

according to the manual the super global `$_FILES` is

```
An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method.
```

So in order to use this global you have to have the images uploaded. I would say that you could avoid multiple requests to the server after you upload the image using jquery and using the `move_uploaded_file()` only after the user has chosen the size he wants.

Doing it the way you have suggested is not possible with only javascript and PHP. AS far as I know at least.

Comment: yes it seems that the full file path is hidden via the browser for security reasonas to protect the user. I was just looking for a shortcut to file uploads as they are time comsuming

Comment: @BarryWatts idipous and I are correct - you can't edit an image on a webpage without uploading the image to the server.